# Is it possible to write the following code in C# code behind using HTMLtable, HTMLDocument, etc?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, database, html-table

```
<script>
function displayDev(id, MAC) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = "MacAddress: " + MAC ;

}
</script>
```

I'm trying to write the function above in C# code behind, wondering if it's possible. I've read through Table class, HTMLdocument and so on.
Unfortunately, I couldn't get a way to rewrite the function above without using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A way to create table on code behind (not very nice in my opinion) is to

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("<table>")
sb.append("   <tr>")
sb.append("      <td>")
sb.append("       MacAddress: " + MAC )
sb.append("      </td>")
sb.append("   </tr>")
sb.append("</table>")

yourField.value = sb.toString()
```

yourField is a runat="server" div

Comment: Thank you so much!! but I have few problems here

I've declared all the tables with different table id in my html(using cshtml page) as follow:

@{ at here,I've written codes to get details from my sql database and trying to get them inserted to my html tables as formed in body below }

<body>
    <table id=LivingRoom>
       <tr>
        <th>Living Room</th>
       </tr>
    </table>

and other tables

</body>

May I know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make table as a server control by adding attribute **runat="server"** and then you can access that table from code behind.

Have a look at the below code sample :

**ASPX Page :**

```
<table runat="server" id="tableMain">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Mack Address
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
var row = new HtmlTableRow();
var cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = "Mac Address : " + "1111";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
tableMain.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I'm actually trying to get the database details using database.open and etc in cshtml, and display them in the Html table according to their "location". 

I have no idea about how to use the ASPX page, may I know if I can create an ASPX page and link it to my cshtml page?

Thank you in advance :)